# Lucene IndexWriter.commit() doesn't finished in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, indexing, lucene, filesystems

Here is initialize code

```
public class Main {

public void index(String input_path, String index_dir, String separator, String extension, String field, DataHandler handler) {

    Index index = new Index(handler);
    index.initWriter(index_dir, new StandardAnalyzer());
    index.run(input_path, field, extension, separator);
}

public List<?> search(String input_path, String index_dir, String separator, String extension, String field, DataHandler handler) {

    Search search = new Search(handler);
    search.initSearcher(index_dir, new StandardAnalyzer());

    return search.runUsingFiles(input_path, field, extension, separator);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String lang = "en-US";
    String dType = "data";

    String train = "res/input/" +lang+ "/" +dType +"/train/";
    String test = "res/input/"+ lang+ "/" +dType+ "/test/";

    String separator = "\\|";
    String extension = "csv";

    String index_dir = "res/index/" +lang+ "." +dType+ ".index";
    String output_file = "res/result/" +lang+ "." +dType+ ".output.json";

    String searched_field = "utterance";

    Main main = new Main();
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler();

    main.index(train, index_dir, separator, extension, searched_field, handler);
    //List<JSONObject> result = (List<JSONObject>) main.search(test, index_dir, separator, extension, searched_field, handler);
    //handler.writeOutputJson(result, output_file); 
}
```

}

---

It is my code

```
public class Index {

private IndexWriter writer;
private DataHandler handler;

public Index(DataHandler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}

public Index() {
    this(new DataHandler());
}

public void initWriter(String index_path, Directory store, Analyzer analyzer) {
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);

    try {
        this.writer = new IndexWriter(store, config);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void initWriter(String index_path, Analyzer analyzer) {

    try {
        initWriter(index_path, FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(index_path)), analyzer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void initWriter(String index_path) {
    List<String> stopWords = Arrays.asList();
    CharArraySet stopSet = new CharArraySet(stopWords, false);
    initWriter(index_path, new StandardAnalyzer(stopSet));
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void indexDocs(List<?> datas, String field) throws IOException {
    FieldType fieldType = new FieldType();
    FieldType fieldType2 = new FieldType();

    fieldType.setStored(true);
    fieldType.setTokenized(true);
    fieldType.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS);

    fieldType2.setStored(true);
    fieldType2.setTokenized(false);
    fieldType2.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < datas.size() ; i++) {
        Map<String,String> temp = (Map<String,String>) datas.get(i);
        Document doc = new Document();

        for(String key : temp.keySet()) {
            if(key.equals(field))
                continue;
            doc.add(new Field(key, temp.get(key), fieldType2));
        }
        doc.add(new Field(field, temp.get(field), fieldType));

        this.writer.addDocument(doc);                   
    }           

}

public void run(String path, String field, String extension, String separator) {
    List<File> files = this.handler.getInputFiles(path, extension);
    List<?> data = this.handler.readDocs(files, separator);
    try {
        System.out.println("start index");
        indexDocs(data, field);
        this.writer.commit();
        this.writer.close();
        System.out.println("done");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run(String path) {
    run(path, "search_field", "csv", "\t");
}
```

I made simple search module using Java and Lucene.

This module consisted of two phase, index and search.

In index phase, It read csv files and convert to Document each row and add to IndexWriter object using `IndexWriter.addDocument()` method.

Finaly, It call `IndexWriter.commit()` method.

It is working well in my local PC (windows)

but in Ubuntu PC, doesn't finished `IndexWriter.commit()` method.

Of course `IndexWriter.flush()` method doesn't work.

What is the problem?

Comment: how do you initialize your index? can you provide any code snippets?

Comment: sure! I attached my code

Comment: thx. looks ok for me... do you get any exceptions? like index locking or permission issues?

Comment: Yes, looks like it is in an infinite loop.

Comment: can you add the stacktrace as well? do you open multiple index writers maybe in multiple threads?

Comment: Thank you so much your help!! and Sorry I late to check your comments. and my last comment is wrong.. I  misunderstanded your comment.
There are no exceptions or any messages, just the job is not over. looks like it is in an infinite loop...!!

Comment: job? how do you initialize the whole thing? may be good to add a logger and see where it stucked if you can't debug it.

Comment: thanks! I attacted code. It stuck in IndexWriter.commit() method. but I don't know how can debug inside of library. and I think filesystem or permission issue.